# Websocket Connection does no longer work with Cordova Android 7

Tags: android, cordova, websocket

I recently updated my Cordova app to Cordova Android 7.1.1 (from 6.x). I'm using websockets in this app to connect to another app running a websocket server, which used to work fine. Now, after upgrading to Cordova Android 7.1.1, the connection can no longer be established. It fails with this message (from the chrome console):

```
WebSocket connection to 'ws://192.168.178.20:52998/' failed: 
Error in connection establishment: net::ERR_ACCESS_DENIED
```

No changes were made in the code which is responsible for establishing the connection. It looks like this:

```
ns.connection = new WebSocket(uri); // uri would be e.g. 'ws://192.168.178.20:52998/'
```

I cannot find the reason for this. I already tried to add CSP headers and more, but to no avail. I made sure the connection is working in general, so it must be somehow related to changes made from Cordova Android 6.x to 7.x I'd guess.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Changes in Cordova included obeying CORS headers.  You have to now make sure your CORS is setup to allow.  For example:

config.xml:

```
<access origin="*" />
<allow-navigation href="*"/>
```

Content-Security-Policy in index.html:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src *; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; media-src *; img-src 'self' data:">
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, worked well for me. Apparently it is enough to just at the first two lines to config.xml.

Comment: Technically they attach to the header.  I like putting the CORS on the site just in case something changes in the future.